# Can't Import gms Location Place

Tags: android, gmsplace

After I Updated `gms:play-services-location` from 9.0.2 to 9.6.1, I couldn't import `com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place` and I couldn't use `PlaceAutoComplete` either.

Was it deprecated or removed from google play service location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [list of split dependencies](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split), to include the places APIs, you must include the dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1'
```

The `places` dependency was only added in Google Play services 9.2.0 - before that, it was part of the `maps` dependency, which was a requirement for `location` (version 9.6.0 also removed the dependency of `location` on `maps`), hence why previously when you included `location` you also got `places`.

Answer (score 0):

add this version in your gradle

**compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'**